# Can't get past Postgres not null constraint

Tags: postgresql, null

I am trying to move data from one table to another:

```
zuri=# INSERT INTO lili_code (uuid, arrow, popularname, slug, effdate, codetext)           
SELECT uuid, arrow, popularname, slug, effdate, codetext
FROM newarts;
ERROR:  null value in column "shorttitle" violates not-null constraint
```

**My Question:
shorttitle is NOT one of the columns I was trying to fill, so why does it matter if it is null or not?**

Please note:

1. shorttitle is blank=True. I understand this is != null, but I thought it might be relevant.
2. There are a lot of additional columns in lili_code besides shorttitle that weren't in newarts.

At this point it looks to me like my only options are

a. inserting by hand (yuck!)

b. making a csv and importing that

c. adding all the missing columns from lili_code to newarts and making sure they are NOT NULL and have at least a default value in them.

Have I missed an option? What's the best solution here? I'm using django 1.9.1, python 2.7.11, Ubuntu 15.10, and Postgresql 9.4.

Thanks as always.

Answer (score 1):

Since the column is non-null, you need to provide a value.

If there is no real data for it, you can calculate it on the fly in the `SELECT` part of your `INSERT` statement, it does not have to be an actual column in the source table.

If you are fine with an empty string, you can do

```
INSERT INTO lili_code 
(uuid, arrow, popularname, slug, effdate, codetext, shorttitle)           
SELECT uuid, arrow, popularname, slug, effdate, codetext, ''
FROM newarts;
```

Or maybe you want to use `popularname` for this column as well:

```
INSERT INTO lili_code 
(uuid, arrow, popularname, slug, effdate, codetext, shorttitle)           
SELECT uuid, arrow, popularname, slug, effdate, codetext, popularname
FROM newarts;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you not define the value on the `INSERT` the db will insert `NULL` or the default value.

If column doesnt allow `NULL` you will get an error. So either provide a dummy value or change the field to allow `NULL`

Answer (score 1):

You can define a default value for the column, e.g.:

```
alter table lili_code alter shorttitle set default '';
```

Comment: this defeats the purpose of putting a non null constraint.

Comment: I don't know what you have in mind. One does not prevent the other. They rather work well together.